# I am trying to create an Alarm on my Android Studio 1.4

Tags: android, performance, alarmmanager, android-alarms

Trying to create a simple Alarm. Reading through the article of Android Dev here
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/AlarmClock.html

I get an idea that the Alarm should go off even when the application is not running and the phone is on sleep mode. I tried all the tutorials available on YT and all the answers I could search for online but using any of these examples I just couldn't make my alarms go off when my phone is asleep. I tried adding wake up permission on the manifest and used wakefulbroadcastreceier insted of simple broadcast receiver but it doesn't help. The alarm goes off only when the app is running in the background. Here is my alarm function

```
 public void _setAlarm()
{
    Long alerttime = new GregorianCalendar().getTimeInMillis()+60*1000;
    Intent _alarmIntent = new Intent(this, Alert.class);
    ArrayList<String> _displayItem = _displayItem();
    _alarmIntent.putStringArrayListExtra("Text1", _displayItem);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alerttime, PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,1,
            _alarmIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));
}
```

And here is the Alert class

```
public class Alert extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    //PendingIntent _alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,0, new Intent(context,Alarm.class),0);
    Intent _alarmIntent = new Intent (context, Alarm.class);
    ArrayList<String> data = intent.getStringArrayListExtra("Text1");
    _alarmIntent.putStringArrayListExtra("Text1",data);
    Uri uri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder _alarmBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setContentTitle("Get up")
            .setContentText("Get Up")
            //.setSound(uri)
            .setTicker("SonsofGun")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.edit_icon);
    TaskStackBuilder tStackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
    tStackBuilder.addParentStack(Alarm.class);
    tStackBuilder.addNextIntent(_alarmIntent);
    PendingIntent _alarmPIntent = tStackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    _alarmBuilder.setContentIntent(_alarmPIntent);
    _alarmBuilder.setDefaults(NotificationCompat.DEFAULT_SOUND);
    //_alarmBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
    NotificationManager _alarmManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    _alarmManager.notify(1, _alarmBuilder.build());
}
```

And the following is my alarm activity with custom expandable list

```
public class Alarm extends AppCompatActivity {
TextView _item, _title;
HashMap<String,List<String>> _itemDisplay;
List<String> _list;
ExpandableListView _expLV;
expLVAdapter _expAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_alarm);


    //Adding font to notification title---------------------------------------------------------
    _title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewNotificationTitle);
    Typeface amaticTF = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Amatic-Bold.ttf");
    _title.setTypeface(amaticTF);

    // End of notification title----------------------------------------------------------------

    _expLV = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.expListView);
    ArrayList<String> _displayItem = getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("Text1");
    _itemDisplay = getInfo(_displayItem);
    _list = new ArrayList<String>(_itemDisplay.keySet());
    _expAdapter = new expLVAdapter(this,_itemDisplay,_list);
    _expLV.setAdapter(_expAdapter);
}
//Adding values to the expandable list view
public static HashMap<String,List<String>> getInfo(ArrayList<String> _displayItem){
    HashMap<String, List<String>> _itemList = new HashMap<String,List<String>>();
    int items = _displayItem.size();
    for(int i = 0; i < items; i++) {
        String _itemName = _displayItem.get(i);
        List<String> itemName = new ArrayList<>();
        itemName.add("some text");
        _itemList.put(_itemName,itemName);
    }
    return _itemList;
}}
```

Kindly help me create a simple alarm, nothing fancy, that wakes the phone up and triggers the activity at a certain time, even when the phone is on sleep and the application has been closed. Some people say that if the application has been closed, alarm will never trigger. But the simple alarm on any android phone goes off irrespective of whether the app is running or not. So it should work. My minimumAPI level is 11